# Compile error during Caffe installation on OS X 10.11

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I've configured Caffe environment on my Mac for several times. But this time I encountered a problem I've never met before:
I use Intel's MKL for accelerating computation instead of ATLAS, and I use Anaconda 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4, with Xcode 7.3.1 on OS X 10.11.6.
when I

```
make all -j8
```

in terminal under Caffe's root directory, the error info is:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/cuda/lib' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(parallel.o) has no symbols

I've tried many times, does anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you haven't changed **Makefile.config** from GPU to CPU mode.  There shouldn't be anything trying to actively link that library.  I think the only CUDA one you should need is libicudata.so

Look for the lines

```
# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1
```

and remove the octothorpe from the front of the second line.